# Organization method for handling routing between many methods

Tags: python, code-organization, project-organization

This may be a matter of opinion, but since I'm mostly self-taught, I'd like to ask for advice. I have an input and then a routing method and then individual methods to handle the routing like so:

```
# Use first char as prefix for routing.
typ_pfx =  input[0]
inb_typ_handler(typ_pfx)

#=== Routing ===#
def _inb_typ_handler(self, typ_pfx):
    try:
        typ_pfx = typ_pfx.upper()

        if typ_pfx == 'M':
            # Default. Prints to screen.
            self._m_handler()
        elif typ_pfx == 'C':
            # Incoming controller message.
            self._c_handler()
        elif typ_pfx == 'S':
            # Server messages.
            self._s_handler()
        elif typ_pfx == 'U':
            # Misc handler....
            self._u_handler()

        # ...
        # ... omitted for succinctness
        # ...

        else:
            print('Prefix: ', typ_pfx)
            print('-x- Unknown message type error.')
    except:
        pass

#=== Handlers ===#
def _m_handler(self):
    """Standard message. Unpacks message, and prints screen."""
    trim_msg = self.unpack_msg(serv_sock)
    self.print_message(trim_msg, enc=self.encrypt_traffic)

def _c_handler(self):
    """Control messages from another user. Not displayed."""
    self.unpack_msg(serv_sock)

def _s_handler(self):
    """Server announcements."""
    msg = self.unpack_msg(serv_sock).decode()
    msg = f"@YO: {msg}"
    self.print_message(msg, style_name='BLUEGREY')

# ... And so on and so forth.
```

Right now, these are all in the same class, ,on the main file (it's for a socket client).

My first instinct is to just move the routers to a module file, and the handlers to a separate module file, and then `import` them.

So inb_typ_handler would be imported from like an `socketIO` module, and then the modules would go into their own handlers module.

I wonder, is there some other way to handle this, make it cleaner or organize it better because my handlers and routers are increasing in number consistently, and it's currently at the point where it's so easy to get lost while scrolling back and forth.

They are using letters as prefix codes, but I have them grouped by functionality and not in alphabetical order. I have heard about @decorators, but have never used them, is there some way I can apply those to help organize my handlers?

Is there anything more I can be doing to make the code clean and easy to read?

Comment: You could create a dictionary that mapped `typ_pfx` values to different methods. This would be faster since the routing is reduced to a simple dictionary look-up operation.

Comment: Oh that's awesome! So how would it work exactly? function = routing_dict[typ_pfx]? how do I call the function from the dict? Would I be able to pass parameters to the functions as well?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea — see answer I added with details.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to implement the things I suggested in comments (based on your example code):

```
class Foobar:
    def inb_typ_handler(self, typ_pfx):
        handler = self.routing_dict.get(typ_pfx.upper(), type(self)._error_handler)
        handler(self, typ_pfx)

    def _m_handler(self, typ_pfx):
        """Standard message. Unpacks message, and prints screen."""
        print('In _m_handler()')

    def _c_handler(self, typ_pfx):
        """Control messages from another user. Not displayed."""
        print('In _c_handler()')

    def _s_handler(self, typ_pfx):
        """Server announcements."""
        print('In _s_handler()')

    def _error_handler(self, typ_pfx):
        raise RuntimeError(f'Unknown message type error: "{typ_pfx}"')

    routing_dict = {  # Create method routing table for class.
        'M': _m_handler,
        'C': _c_handler,
        'S': _s_handler,
    }


# Sample usage.
foobar = Foobar()
foobar.inb_typ_handler('m')
foobar.inb_typ_handler('s')
foobar.inb_typ_handler('x')    # An invalid message type.
```

Output produced from above example:

```
In _m_handler()
In _s_handler()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "routing_example.py", line 39, in <module>
    foobar.inb_typ_handler('x')
  File "routing_example.py", line 9, in inb_typ_handler
    handler(self, typ_pfx)
  File "routing_example.py", line 24, in _error_handler
    raise RuntimeError(f'Unknown message type error: "{typ_pfx}"')
RuntimeError: Unknown message type error: "x"
```